# Javascript + CSS: Converting from absolute positioned elements to CSS Transforms (left, top, width, height to translateX, translateY, scale)

Tags: webkit, javascript, zepto, css-transforms

I'd like to convert a Javascript carousel to work smoothly on the iOS devices iPad and iPhone, and Android devices which use webkit that is able to take advantage of hardware acceleration of CSS transforms.

Is there already a library or some snippets of code that would allow position and size setting?

I found [jquery.animate-enhanced](http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/) which may be close but it requires animations, and also does feature detection - I want to do something simpler, it looks significantly more complex than that.

There are several complexities I suspect the solution needs to address:

-Simple reuse of code to use either `top` / `left` CSS attributes or CSS transforms with translation (and any recalculation needed to convert them)

-Using the scale transform instead of setting width and height

Setup steps like:

-Setting `-webkit-transform-style` to `preserve-3d`

-Setting `-webkit-transform-origin` if needed (and what to?)

Answer (score 0):

I see Zepto in the tags, so it seems like you've considered it and it didn't work? Zepto does use CSS3 for its animations.

I would try something like this as a first guess. You'll need to do your feature detection outside of the 'animateLeft' method because the animation apis are different between jquery and zepto.

Maybe something like this (psuedocode):

```
isTouchy = Modernizr.touch

var slideRight = function() {
    if (isTouchy) {
        Zepto('#carosel').animate(...)
    } else {
        jQuery('#carosel').slideRight() //sorry, don't know the api
    }
}
```

http://zeptojs.com/#animate

http://modernizr.com/

Comment: I'm not using jQuery actually, only Zepto but they are cousins hence the tags.
Does zepto's animate convert from absolute positioned elements to CSS Transforms?
I think my main hurdle was figuring out that the X and Y translations need multiplying by the scale transform, got me a lot of the way there, a bit of a face slapping, oh yeah that's why they don't work moment. Maybe I should answer the question myself now I can. I hoped something already existed - maybe the animation function is more clever than I thought. Either way, thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: I actually haven't used Zepto's animations. I typically do them manually by building css classes and using JS to swap classes. Maybe that is the wrong approach, or too verbose, but at least I can trust what is going on.